# jdk 11 - package javax.xml.bind.annotation is declared in the unnamed module, but module javax.xml.bind.annotation does not read it

Tags: jaxb, java-11

I red all other topics (maybe work for jdk 10) and still have problem to run `javax.xml.bind` on **jdk 11**.

**My dependency:**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0-b180830.0359</version>                   <!--  2.2.12, 2.3.1  -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0-b180830.0438</version>                   <!-- 2.3.1 -->
        <!--<scope>compile</scope>-->
        <!--<scope>runtime</scope>-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.activation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

My IDE (newest intellij) still doesn't see import:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
```

Also my module-info.java doesnt see:

```
requires java.xml.bind;
```

And when i use maven i have an error:

> [ERROR] ...ExceptionType.java:[6,22] package javax.xml.bind.annotation is not visible
>     (package javax.xml.bind.annotation is declared in the unnamed module, but module javax.xml.bind.annotation does not read it)

anybody run it on jdk 11 ?

edit:
1) App version with java module system:
i have similar problem to this:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-197956
but my error message is a little difrent

2) App version without java module system:
Maven compile correctly. Problem is that intellij dont see my imports:

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
```

and say: cannot resolve symbol.
Also at file > project structure > modules > dependencies intellij didnt add javax.xml.bind and org.glassfish.jaxb
Why?
I added this in pom:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0-b180830.0359</version>                   <!-- 2.2.8, 2.4.0-b180830.0359  -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0-b180830.0438</version>                   <!-- 2.3.0, 2.4.0-b180830.0438 -->
    </dependency>
```

JDK: openjdk11
Intellij version: IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.4 (Ultimate Edition), Build #IU-182.4505.22, built on September 18, 2018, JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b8 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Maven:3.5.4

It seems to be a intellij bug.

Comment: Can you share the `module-info.java` and compilation configuration of maven as well in the question, please?

Comment: The error hints that the project has a module named "javax.xml.bind.annotation" that `requires java.xml.bind` but the module has been put on the class path rather than the module name.

Comment: First i tried without module-info.java and then also IDE didnt see java.xml.bind :/ I have correct project compilling at jdk 8 and now have only problem with this package. My module-info.java is correct and only dont see java.xml.bind

Comment: ...In my project of course i dont have module named "javax.xml.bind.annotation" - this message comes outside of my project (maybe from "javax.xml.bind" ?)

Comment: I have problem with intellij probably. In my sub-module intellij read from pom.xml only dependencies: javax.activation and javax.annotation. And he doesnt read javax.xml.bind and org.glassfish.jaxb (in file > project structure > modules > dependencies i dont have these dependencies). Now i convert my app and dont use module-info.java but i see that org.glassfish.jaxb jaxb-runtime  over ver 2.3.0 has inside file module-info.class but in oldest versions he hasnt this file. So maybe here is some reason. anybody could help ?:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We managed to find the cause of the problem. In ide intellij I have a modules maven project and I use JLupin Platform Development Tool, so in *.iml files i dont have line:

'<'module org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsManager.isMavenModule = "true" type = "JAVA_MODULE" version = "4">
but i have for example:

'<'module org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsManager.isMavenModule = "true" type = "JLP_NATIVE_MICROSERVICE_IMPLEMENTATION_MODULE_TYPE" version = "4">

During the development, the names of the modules were changed, then the idea asked whether to remove modules (because ide did not recognize:

type = "JLP_NATIVE_MICROSERVICE_IMPLEMENTATION_MODULE_TYPE").
Although the chosen option was not, then ide automatically performed:

- selecting the maven module as ignored
- replace in the iml file from:
  '<'module org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsManager.isMavenModule = "true" type = "JLP_NATIVE_MICROSERVICE_IMPLEMENTATION_MODULE_TYPE" version = "4">
  to:
  '<'module type = "JLP_NATIVE_MICROSERVICE_IMPLEMENTATION_MODULE_TYPE" version = "4">

For the above reason, the project did not correctly read the maven artifacts. After unifying the names and marking the project as not ignored, it works correctly.
The problem is not related to java packages

EDIT: its resolved as above

Answer (score 0):

Switched back to JDK 1.8 and it fixed this issue for me. How to switch in ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/740757/switch-between-multiple-java-versions

Comment: its resolved, dont need to downgrade jdk